# Meaning of the word 爆誕

Tags: meaning, kanji

This movie title:

> 劇場版ポケットモンスター幻のポケモンルギア**爆誕**

Is officially translated into English as:

> Pocket Monster Revelation Lugia

I'm really curious about the 爆誕 part of the title. If I break the kanji down, I think the meaning is something like 'explosive' and 'rebirth'. I've tried searching for more info about this compound, but it doesn't seem to be used often. My question is, is understanding it as 'revelation' in English accurate?

Comment: http://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E7%88%86%E8%AA%95 According to this page, 爆誕 is a kind of word they use in manga or in _Finnegans Wake_ :)

Answer (score 5):

It is a "commercial slang" newly coined from 「**爆**発的な**誕**生」(**ばく**はつてきな**たん**じょう), which means "**explosive birth**".

It does not really mean "revelation", but there may be contexts where that translation might be valid.

As a Japanese-speaker, I could attest to the impactfulness of how 「[爆誕]{ばくたん}」 both looks and sounds.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a real word, obviously.

It's probably an abbreviation of 爆発誕生, putting the words *explosion* and *birth* together. [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/M02) takes this literally and translates it as *explosive birth*. However, I think the 爆発 also could just be making the 誕生 part sound more epic;「幻のポケモンルギア**誕生**」does not sound as exciting of a movie title.